# I want only all array from phalcon translate object properties?

Tags: php, arrays, oop, phalcon

When i `var_dump($t)` output like this

```
$t = object(Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray)[121]
protected '_translate' => 
array (size=14)
  'attendancelist' => string 'ယေန႕စာရင္း' (length=30)
  'monthlylist' => string 'လစဥ္တက္ေရာက္စာရင္း' (length=54)
  'bye' => string 'sayounara' (length=9)
  'hi-name' => string 'Bonjour %name%' (length=14)
  'song' => string 'La chanson est %song%' (length=21)
  'todaylist' => string '' (length=0)
  'date' => string 'ရက္စြဲ' (length=18)
  'username' => string 'နာမည္' (length=15)
  'checkin' => string '' (length=0)
  'late' => string 'ေနာက္က်ခ်ိန္' (length=36)
  'checkout' => string '' (length=0)
  'workingtime' => string 'အလုပ္ခ်ိန္' (length=30)
  'overtime' => string 'အခ်ိန္ပို' (length=27)
  'location' => string 'ေနရာ' (length=12)
```

> I want just all array so i try `$t->_translate` is not ok.
>
> but the correct code is `$t->_("attendancelist");` is ok....however i want all array not individual ..

My want array is

```
  array (size=14)
  'attendancelist' => string 'ယေန႕စာရင္း' (length=30)
  'monthlylist' => string 'လစဥ္တက္ေရာက္စာရင္း' (length=54)
  'bye' => string 'sayounara' (length=9)
  'hi-name' => string 'Bonjour %name%' (length=14)
  'song' => string 'La chanson est %song%' (length=21)
  'todaylist' => string '' (length=0)
  'date' => string 'ရက္စြဲ' (length=18)
  'username' => string 'နာမည္' (length=15)
  'checkin' => string '' (length=0)
  'late' => string 'ေနာက္က်ခ်ိန္' (length=36)
  'checkout' => string '' (length=0)
  'workingtime' => string 'အလုပ္ခ်ိန္' (length=30)
  'overtime' => string 'အခ်ိန္ပို' (length=27)
  'location' => string 'ေနရာ' (length=12)
```

Help me to get all array??

Comment: Does `$t->getTranslate()` works?

Comment: No its doesn't work  @M2sh

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I see is to implement `toArray()` method:

```
class NativeArrayExt extends \Phalcon\Translate\Adapter\NativeArray {
    public function toArray() {
        return $this->_translate;
    }
}
```

or to reimplement `_()` to do the same if no parameter providen.